# Angular template loading without data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

Having a really weird issue where my template loads without any data in it, but when I refresh the page enough times, the data eventually does load. I am not sure what is going on or how to fix this.  I'll add some code below. Let me know if you need other pieces.

Server:

```
  app.get('/api/listings/:listingId', auth.ensureAuthenticated, controllers.listings.show);
```

Controller:

```
function show(req, res) {
  db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
    if(err) { console.log('listingsController.show error', err); }
    res.json(foundListing);
 });
}
```

Http request in Angular Controller :

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/listings/'+$stateParams.listingId
}).then(function successCallback(json) {
  vm.listing = json.data;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log('There was an error getting the data', response);
});
```

A piece of my template:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <h4 class='inline-header'>Topic:</h4>
  <span>{{listingShowCtrl.listing.topic}}</a></span>

</li>
```

Comment: Where does the `editing` flag get set?

Comment: Sorry, that was actually from an older part I forgot to remove. The editing button was moved to another page. I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** if you try declaring it as a scope variable like so: `$scope.listing = json.data;`
Are you still unable to see the data in the view?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the editing flag was from an older version that I forgot to remove. I've updated the html and tested the code. Still doing the same thing without edit flags

Comment: @Kenzo if you console.log() the vm.listing variable, do you always get the data you expect? Have you considered making it a $scope variable to be accessed from the view?

Comment: Yes I always get the data I expect and the console log returns the correct data every time. Just doesn't seem to load right away.

Comment: I am still unable to see the data. I made sure to add $scope to the controller as well. It also seems like with this change, it does not load at all even after multiple refreshes.

Comment: @Kenzo then I guess I'm all out of suggestions, sorry about that :/
Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a race condition - meaning that `listing` is not available yet. `ng-if` will keep on checking every `$digest` cycle and update when it's available.

Try this:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-if="listingShowCtrl.listing">
  <h4 class="inline-header">Topic:</h4>
  <span>{{listingShowCtrl.listing.topic}}</a></span>
</li>
```

Comment: After adding that, I just get a blank screen upon load. If I refresh maybe 4 or 5 times, it will eventually load the entire data + template so essentially doing the same thing.